# Infrared bound on Ising model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, greens-functions, correlation-functions, ising-model

I'm currently trying to understand aspects of Hugo Duminil-Copin's [Lectures on the Ising and Potts models on the hypercubic lattice](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.00520). In section 4.3, he claims that for the Ising model in $\mathbb{Z}^d$, the infrared bound tells us that if $\beta <\beta_c$, then
$$
\langle \sigma_x \sigma_y\rangle^\text{f} \le \frac{C}{\beta} G(x,y)
$$
Where the superscript f denotes free boundary conditions, and $G(x,y)$ is the Green function of the simple random walk.

I don't quite see how this follows readily from the infrared bound. Indeed, he references Fröhlich, Simon and Spencer's paper (Comm. Math. Phys. 50(1): 79-95 (1976)), but even within that paper, the authors say "Caution. Alas (2.9) does not imply $\langle \sigma_a\sigma_b\rangle -\langle \sigma_a\rangle^2$ is pointwise bounded by $(-\Delta)^{-1}_{ab}$". Any insight would be appreciated.

**Just a reminder**. The infrared bound tells us that on a finite $d$-dim torus, we have
$$
\langle (\sigma(-\Delta h))^2\rangle\le\frac{1}{2\beta}(-h\Delta h)
$$
Take $h=e^{ikx}$ and the usual form follows. We can also take $h$ such that $-\Delta h =\delta_x -\delta_y$. Then we do indeed get some information about the correlations $\langle \sigma_x \sigma_y\rangle$. However, it gives us a lower bound, which isn't quite surprising since the infrared bound is used to prove spontaneous symmetry breaking in $d\ge 3$ dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stated inequality follows from the infrared bound and [an inequality by Messager and Miracle-Sole](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01040105) that states monotonicity of the 2-point function of the Ising model as you move the endpoints in suitable directions. The original derivation of the pointwise bound on the 2-point function you are interested in is due to Alan Sokal and can be found in Appendix A (*Universal bounds on the 2-point function*) of [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIHPA_1982__37_4_317_0/).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. Thanks! And just a follow up, it seems that the proof is only for $d>2$ dimensions, but it would seem that one should be able to find something similar for $d=1,2$ dimensions. I know there is a proof for the planar XY model (McBryan and Spencer), but that is only for sufficiently low temperatures. Do you know of more general proofs?

Comment: In dimension $1$, the decay is always exponential, so it is not clear to me what bound you'd like in this case. In dimension $2$, at least for the planar Ising model, one has explicit expressions for the two-point function in all regimes. Concerning the McBryan-Spencer argument, it's true that it relies on $\beta$ being large, but I would be surprised if a slight variant could not be used to get power law decay at all $\beta$; note that, at small $\beta$, the bound is again poor, since the decay is exponential in this case.

Comment: For the planar Ising model at $\beta<\beta_c$, one can also directly relate the 2-point function of the model with the Green function of a (killed) random walk, using the parafermionic observable. This is done in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41713976).

Comment: One last comment: for finite-range interactions, there is an alternative to the McBryan-Spencer bound, due to Dobrushin and Shlosman, which does not require $\beta$ to be large. The argument is described (in a more general setting) in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002200200627); see Theorem 1.